# Book on gamma functions with applications in physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematics, integration, special-functions

I have heard that in my next semester, our quantum mechanics teacher will be giving a great emphasis on difficult integrals with the most of them having to do with [gamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Does anybody know a book(or any other source) that I can learn about and practice gamma functions integration (with applications to physics and more preferably quantum mechanics if possible)?

The only thing I have found are books that just list the integrals of gamma functions in tables rather than having a few examples and them some practice problems.

Comment: You can try Mathematical Methods for Physicists by Arfken if that's your thing. It generally shows the properties for something, its derivation and a few examples before going to the problems. Actually if I remember correctly, the newest edition of Arfken has a full chapter dedicated to the gamma function, and other functions related to it (actually the book has every thing related to math for physics).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link will be your best bet at finding a free book on this topic: http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Artin%20E.%20The%20Gamma%20Function%20(1931)(23s).pdf

If you're like me and despise reading on PDF's and prefer reading print, The few books I can recommend that won't break your budget are:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Gamma-Function-Dover-Books-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00T2QF51C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442703641&sr=8-1&keywords=dover+books+gamma+functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T2QF51C)
  (The Gamma Function (Dover Books on Mathematics), Emil Artin)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Functions-Mathematical-Physics-Dover-Books/dp/0486652149/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1442703641&sr=8-3&keywords=dover+books+gamma+functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486652149)
  (The Functions of Mathematical Physics (Dover Books on Physics), Harry Hochstadt)

Those are what I can recommend and I think they will serve you well. I love Dover books and use them for many supplemental texts in my courses.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of links, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: They all seem to be helpful. I also found Nahin's book "Inside interesting Integrals" to laso be very helpful with gamma functions(for anybody else who is interested besides me).